# CSS mask not working properly in Angular 5

Tags: css, angular, svg, mask

I'm trying to create an Angular 5 app that consists of a masked/clipped image.

In plain ol' HTML + CSS, I can achieve what I want with the following code pen: https://codepen.io/earthican/pen/BJjgRv

```css
body,
html,
.img {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: white;
  overflow: hidden;
}

svg {
  pointer-events: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  background: transparent;
  fill: transparent;
  mask: url(#polygon-mask);
}
```

```html
<svg id="mask">
<defs>
  <mask id="polygon-mask" x="0" y="0" width="960" height="588" >
    <rect id="reverse-mask" fill="white" x="0" y="0" width="960" height="588" ></rect>
    <polygon fill="red" points="112,62 162,112 162,162 62,162 62,112"></polygon>
  </mask>
  </defs>
  <rect width="960" height="588" fill="teal"></rect>
</svg>
<div class="img">
  <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/53/5e/5b/535e5b3744dbb8264a7ebba5f29f44ca.jpg" style="margin-left: 0px; margin-top: 0px;">
</div>
```

However, I'm having trouble trying to convert the above to Angular. Here's what I have so far: https://plnkr.co/edit/w2gVe91NEIdUlCWs3qkN?p=preview

I think I'm starting to realize that Angular doesn't play very well with SVG. I should also point out that I'm *fairly* new to Angular 2+ and SVG, so I can't really be sure. If anyone can help or point out some useful resources, that will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this by moving the `mask` attribute from CSS to the SVG tree, i.e.:

```
<svg mask="url(#polygon-mask)">
  ...
</svg>
```